# Removing VSTS link from a project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have a project that is connected to our repository on VSTS. I made a copy of it to try out a few ideas. Once done, I'll discard that copy and I don't want to branch it out on VSTS.

When I open the project, it tells me that the project is on VSTS. How do I remove that so that the project that is a copy of the original has no knowledge of VSTS?

Comment: Is it a git project ?

Comment: No, it's a TFS project

Comment: Do you mean Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC). TFS support two version control systems, TFVC and Git. TFS relates to the platform.

Comment: Yes, it's TFVC. It is NOT Git.

Answer (score 3):

You need to unbind the source control via following steps first:

1. Open your project from VS.
2. Select "File\Source Control\Advanced\Change Source Control".
3. Click "Unbind" button to unbind your project with the TFS.
4. Save the sln file and close VS.

Now you can make a copy of the project. Remember to re-bind the original project to TFS after you copy it.